# Telegram bot ASP.NET MVC InlineKeyboardButton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bots, telegram

In ASP.NET MVC using C#, I can not receive `CallbackQuery`.  I have `InlineKeyoardButton` but when I click on it, in the telegram bot, it doesn't work.

Everything work so will just inline button dos not work.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Args;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups;

namespace FinalBot.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public static long chatId;
        public static string message;
        
        public static TelegramBotClient bot;
        [HttpPost()]
        public void Index(Update update)
        {
            bot = new TelegramBotClient("bot token");

            chatId = update.Message.Chat.Id;
            message = update.Message.Text;

            if (message.Contains("start"))
            {
                InlineKeyboardButton a = new InlineKeyboardButton()
                {
                    Text = "about",
                    CallbackData = "a"
                };

                InlineKeyboardButton[] row1 =
                {
                    a
                };

                InlineKeyboardMarkup inline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(row1);

                bot.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, "select", replyMarkup: inline);
            }

            if (update.CallbackQuery != null)
            {
                bot.SendTextMessageAsync("myChat ID", "callback is ok");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when someone click on the inline button nothing will happen I tried so many things I still can't solve the problem

//help//

Comment: Hi. did you set callback delay in botfother? check your bot's settings in `botfother`

Comment: Hi. I checked my bot's settings but there are nothing like callback delay in the settings (In botfather)

Comment: I double check that, and there is `/setinlinefeedback` setting. set that

Comment: Not working yet. Do you have a sample code for inline button and callback ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't work because updates for `Message` and `Callback` are different and `Callback` Update can't give you `.Message`
Add check for `.Message` or change the way you process `Updates`, because doing all of then in one method is actually bad idea

```
if (update.Message != null) {
   // process message here
   // or
   // ProcessMessage(update.Message);
   return;
}
if (update.CallbackQuery != null) {
   // process callback query here
   // or
   // ProcessCallback(update.CallbackQuery);
   return;
}
```